# How to detach eclipselink loaded entity to serialize it via jaxb or yasson?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jaxb, jersey, eclipselink, detach

I want to load entities using eclipselink and to send it to client (via REST Services) using JAXB for Serialization. How to detach entities to make JAXB not loading lazy relationships on managed entities ? I don't want to serialize full structure of my entity but just what I need.

I already tried to clear (clear()) the entityManager but when serializing, Jaxb and EclipseLink still load non initialised lazy relationships. Same results with entityManager.detach(myobject). I saw is this topic (https://community.oracle.com/message/1708796) that EclipseLink still load lazy relationships even after a detach call.

My question is : how can I finally detach properly the JPA loaded entity in the way to serialize it without sending big and useless amount of data ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know the answer but the question is why do you load entites if you don't want to serialize everything?

Comment: Because I have a big structure of data and sometimes it generates heavy xml files (100Mo, 200Mo...) and I don't need all that data just for showing the parent entity main attributes. I don't also want to put all my lists as @XmlTransient because I don't want to call big quantities of webservices when I need to load each list of the parent entity. 
I wanted to use  NamedEntityGraphs to make JPA load what I need and not more. But each time I serialize it, Eclipselink still load all the structure.

Comment: And why don't you use DTOs?

Comment: I don't know a lot about DTO but from what I saw, it will make my whole projects being much more complex while a simple entityManager.detach() or entityManager.clear() before serialization should solve my problem. How to detach an object when using eclipselink ?

Comment: No it would make it much more clear if you have dedicated classes instead of partially loaded entities.